# If $AB+BA=0$, then $A^2B^3=B^2A^3$?

Tags: matrices

If I have a matrix $A$ and $B$ such that $AB+BA=0$

is it true that $A^2B^3=B^2A^3$?

I think that it is false.

Comment: I think it is false as well.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106495/form-of-anticommuting-matrices

Answer (score 5):

It is false. Take
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0  & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right),\qquad
B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1  & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right),$$
then we have $AB+BA=0$, but also $A^2=B^2=1$ so that $A^2B^3=B$ and $B^2A^3=A$.

Comment: Neat counter-example. +1

Comment: How did you find this?

Comment: @DanUznanski For a physicist, the most natural example of anticommuting matrices is given by Pauli matrices. Otherwise one could of course just multiply $A$ by a scalar.

Comment: Another way now that I've seen @ChrisCutler's answer is that these two matrices are equivalent to the quaternions $k$ and $i$ respectively, using the 2x2 matrix in $\mathbb C$ form.  Or that times -i, in any case.

Comment: @O.L. I should keep the Pauli matrices in mind. I'm ashamed of myself as a former physicist. I was having trouble coming up with examples of commuting matrices...

Answer (score 4):

Similarly to O.L.'s answer, we have the quaternions $ij+ji=k-k=0$, but $i^2j^3=j$ and $j^2i^3=i$.