# What does diagonalizing one of the pair of anticommuting matrices do to the other?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

If two Hermitian matrices anticommute, $MN=-NM$, then if we diagonalize $M$, does $N$ take a particular form? Block antidiagonal, or strictly antidiagonal?
From a few really old answers on the site this is what I have gathered: When $M^2=N^2=\mathbb{I}$ (Identity), then M can be written as
$$
M = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \mathbb{I} & 0 \\ 0 & -\mathbb{I} \end{array}\right)
$$
and $N$ can be brought to a form
$$
N = \left(\begin{array}{cc}  0 & B \\ B^{-1} & 0 \end{array}\right)
$$
In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/106701/124925), the block $B$ is supposed to be 'similar to' Identity on the antidiagonal blocks, but I fail to see how and no explanation is provided, although asked for in the comments.

What happens when we do not have the assumption $N^2=\mathbb{I}$? Is there a way to bring the matrix $N$ to a strictly antidiagonal form?

EDIT:
This is for a research project, and I am unable to find this in literature. We will of course cite the solution given here.

Comment: Considering the matrix $M$ to be diagonal with real entries, represent it as 
$$
M=\operatorname{diag}(a_1,\ldots,a_r,b_1,\ldots,b_s,0,\ldots,0)
$$ 
where $a_i>0$, $b_i<0$.

Comment: That is true because it is a Hermitian matrix. Plus, when $M$ is also an involution, then on diagonalization, the diagonal entries will only be $\pm 1$.

Comment: Note that $(MN)^* = N^*M^*=NM =-(MN)$  so $MN$ is skew hermitian.  You can define the skew-hermitian form $\langle \mathbf x, \mathbf y\rangle = \mathbf x^*(MN)\mathbf y$.   Let $\mathbf q_j$ and $\mathbf q_k$ be eigenvectors of $M$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ and $\lambda_k$ respectively, then $\langle \mathbf q_i, \mathbf q_k\rangle = 0$  with exception only when $\lambda_j + \lambda_k =0$.